# Unable to select a box in a python script when launching Blender from console

Tags: python, blender

For my project, I want to be able to run a Blender python script from the system console.

This minimal script (see below) is able to select a region, using the *select_box* operator. The script works correctly when launching from the blender application. However, when running it from the console, using `"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\blender.exe" "C:\Users\Desktop\test.blend" -d --python "D:\Documents\minTest.py"`, the program crash with the following output:

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.81 (sub 16)
Build: 2019-12-04 14:30:40 Windows Release
argv[0] = C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\blender.exe
argv[1] = C:\Users\Desktop\test.blend
argv[2] = -d
argv[3] = --python
argv[4] = D:\Documents\minTest.py
Read prefs: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\config\userpref.blend
read file
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\python
Warning: Add-on 'io_mesh_xyz' was not upgraded for 2.80, ignoring
Warning: Add-on 't26_PointCloudSkinner1_Umbrella' was not upgraded for 2.80, ignoring
Read blend: C:\Users\Desktop\test.blend
read file C:\Users\Desktop\test.blend
  Version 281 sub 16 date 2019-12-04 11:32 hash f1aa4d18d49d
***** DEBUG: working
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF60F40DCFD
Module  : C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\blender.exe
```

The *test.blend* file is the simple startup scene. The *minTest.py* script is the following:

```
import bpy

def getView3dAreaAndRegion():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == "WINDOW":
                    return area, region

view3dArea, view3dRegion = getView3dAreaAndRegion()
override = bpy.context.copy()
override['area'] = view3dArea
override['region'] = view3dRegion

print("***** DEBUG: working") #Debug to see that the script has launched
bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(override,xmin=100, xmax=500, ymin=100, ymax=300, wait_for_input=False)
```

More information:

- I'm using Blender 2.81 and Python 3.7 (bundled in Blender).
- The script works just fine if I remove the call to *select_box* in both Blender and from console.

So my questions are:

- Why do I have different result according to how I launch the script?
- What should I do to be able to run the script from the system console?

Comment: While the crash is technically a bug I don't expect anyone will spend time trying to fix it. Basically you are telling blender to respond to UI events before the UI is setup. I am on a *nix system and don't get the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect consistent results if you want to imitate user input with a script, it is too hard to know where anything is positioned.

To get reliable results from a script, you need to work with consistent data, so compare the objects location to decide if it is within certain criteria.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.location.z > 0.2 and obj.location.z < 1.5:
        obj.select_set(True)
    else:
        obj.select_set(False)
```

If you want to select a portion of a mesh, decide on what is selected either based on its position relative to the object origin or its world position by using [`obj.matrix_world`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world).

While you can directly access the [mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) components in [`obj.data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.data), you should consider using [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) for any mesh editing.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
me = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for v in bm.verts:
    if v.co.z > -1.8 and v.co.z < 0.5:
        v.co.z += 0.2
        v.select = True
    else:
        v.select = False

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
bm.free()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

For help with blender specific scripting ask at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com).